# Node has data but multer req.file.path is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer, cloudinary

For several days now I try to upload videofiles via multer to cloudinary. The upload of images works absolutely well, but when I upload a video I face the error:

> Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

I logged my FormData the whole way from the frontend via redux-slice and redux-service. Everywhere the field "src" is a file. I logged the headers of the http-request. And they where there. Finally I logged now req.body and must determine, that node has the data.

> { [0]   src: 'Pexels Videos 2098989.mp4', [0]   ressort: 'Freizeit',
> [0]   theme: 'Lorem Iosum', [0]   title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
> consectetur adipisicing' [0] } [0] (node:4260)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'path' of undefined

What do I have to do to get multer to give me the path of src? I tried now something like `const {req.body.src} = req.file`, but that not works.
I have now responded to robertklep's response and taken out all my debugging code. Maybe it's more readable now. But it doesn't change the situation. req.file.path is still undefined.
My backend (current state):

```
const uploadVideo = upload.single("src");
router.post("/", uploadVideo, verifyTokenAndAuthorization, async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path, {
            upload_preset: "Mern_redux-practice",
            resource_type: "video",
        }
        );
        const newVideos= new Videos({
            cloudinary_id: result.public_id,
            ressort: req.body.ressort,
            theme: req.body.theme,
            title:req.body.title,
            src: result.secure_url,
        })
        const savedVideos= await newVideos.save();
        res.status(200).json(savedVideos);
    } catch(error){
        res.status(403)
        console.log(error)
        throw new Error("Action failed");
    }
});
```

My multer:

```
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const maxSize = 5 * 1024 *1024;
 const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination:(req,file, callback)=>{
            callback(null,  path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'frontside/public/uploads'));
        },
        fileName: (req, file, callback)=>{
            callback(null, Date.now()+ "--"+ path.extname(file.originalname));
            console.log(req.file);
        },
    })

const upload = multer({
    storage:storage,
     fileFilter:(req,file,callback)=>{
        if(
            file.mimetype == "image/png"||
            file.mimetype == "image/jpg" ||
            file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" ||
            file.mimetype == "video/mp3" ||
            file.mimetype == "video/mp4"
        ){
            callback(null, true);
        } else{
            callback(null,false)
            return callback(new Error("Only .png, .jpg, .jpeg, .mp3, .m4 allowed"))
        }
    },
    limits:{fileSize: maxSize}
});

module.exports = upload;
```

I add the whole way. My frontend(input):

```
<FormGroup>
   <CrudLabel htmlFor="src">Video hochladen</CrudLabel>
   <CrudInput type="file" name="src" id="src"  
    style={{background:"var(--blue)", color:"var(--white)"}}
    ref={fileInput} onChange={fileChange}/>
  </FormGroup>
```

My FormData:

```
const onSubmit = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
   const videosData = new FormData();
   videosData.append("ressort", formdata.ressort);
   videosData.append("theme", formdata.theme);
   videosData.append("title", formdata.title);
   videosData.append("src", filedata);
   for(let value of videosData){
    console.log(value);
   }
    dispatch(createVideos(videosData));
  }
```

My video-slice:

```
export const createVideos = createAsyncThunk("videos/create", async (videosData, thunkAPI)=>{
    if(videosData){
        for(let value of videosData){
            console.log(value)
        }
    }
    try{
        const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.accessToken;
        return await videosService.createVideos(videosData, token);
    } catch(error){
        const message = (error.response 
            && error.response.data 
            && error.response.data.message) 
            || error.message 
            || error.toString();
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
})
```

My http-request:

```
const API_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/videos/";
//create
const createVideos = async (videosData, token)=>{
    if(videosData){
        for(let value of videosData){
            console.log(value);
        }
    }
    const config = {
        headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        token: `Bearer ${token}` 
        }
    }
    const response = await axios.post(API_URL, videosData, config);
    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data;
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `uploadVideo` twice? First as a regular middleware in your route declaration, then again in `fileupload()`. Also, you're using `.any()` which, according to [the fine manual](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#any), will place files in `req.files` (plural), not `req.file` (singular).

Comment: Thanks for your answer robertklep. That belongs all to debugging. I changed it now back to upload.single() and I get an empty border on my site. The fileupload() is my try to get a multer.error.

Comment: So `req.file` is undefined in your route handler? Does the `console.log()` in the storage handler get called? How exactly are you uploading the file data?

Comment: @robertklep I added now my whole way. Everywhere you see a console.log comes out the correct data. Only console.log(response.data) is empty.

Comment: what's the response you get back from cloudinary? Is your videos over 100MB? If so use https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#chunked_asset_upload. Another thing you can try is upload_stream, https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007581379-Correct-way-of-uploading-from-buffer-

Comment: Hello Tom, I tried upload_stream, but it cannot work. I don't no why, but the req.body is there, multer loggs the correct file data and req.file is still undefined.

Comment: if req.file is showing as undefined then it's still not being passed properly to your backend, I would check the whole pipeline from frontend and backend to see where the problem might be.

Answer (score -1):

```
headers : {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

That's not the correct header for FormData, it should be `multipart/form-data` (but I assume that Axios will set it if you don't set it manually).

Comment: Sadly not. I tried it, with setting multipart/form-data and without setting any Content-type. The site is pending, breaks and reloads. Console.log(req.file) in multer storage brings undefined.

Comment: If the storage handler `fileName` handler gets called (which is strange though, because according to the documentation, it should be `filename`, all lower case), at least Multer is seeing that you're trying to upload form data, so that's good. I wouldn't expect `req.file` to exist at that point yet, so try logging `file` instead.

Comment: Logging file brings  {
[0]   fieldname: 'src',
[0]   originalname: 'Pexels Videos 2098989.mp4',
[0]   encoding: '7bit',
[0]   mimetype: 'video/mp4'
[0] }

Comment: I tried now to give cloudinary upload_large, but nothing changes. But multer has the file. Node has the full data.

Comment: It all sounds like Multer is receiving the file just fine. Are you sure the file size is smaller than 5MB?

Comment: Raised it to 100MB. And I use const {path} = req.file. When I hover "path", vs-code tells me: DiskStorage only: full path to the uploaded file. When I hover file it tells me: Express.Multer.File. Than I pass "path" into the upload_large but it is not uploaded.

Comment: I don't really care what VS Code thinks about it, it's the actual contents of `req.file` when the request comes in that are important.